# Retornar a una pagina luego de enviar mensaje con sweet alert

Tags: jquery, ajax, sweetalert

```
if ($resultado) {
   $mysql->commit();
   echo "<script>
   jQuery(function(){
   swal(\"¡Inscripción realizada exitosamente!\", \"Sus datos fueron enviados correctamente \", \"success\");
}
window.history.go(-1);
);
</script>";
```

Buenas noches a todos ,

Estoy sin poder hacer funcionar el window.history.go(-1)
Necesito que una vez se haya realizado un INSERT en la Base de Datos, se muestre un alert , en este caso con sweet alert y luego retorne a la pagina del formulario , pero no se como hacerlo.

¿Por favor podrian orientarme para resolver esto ?
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Con un simple window.location, espero haber ayudado
        `window.location.replace("urldelformulario.php");`

Comment: Compañero gracias por la respuesta pero no funciona

Comment: window.location.replace(\"urldelformulario.php\");
Agregué las barras invertidas y funcionó .
Gracias y saludos.

Comment: eso es por que usabas php con js sin cerrar etiquetas mesclando los 2 lenguajes